# about nested transaction, the outer scope gives me "The Transaction has been aborted" exception, but the inner scope returns succesfully

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clr, transactionscope

I got a wired problem need your help. I have nested transactions. The outer method calls an inner method SaveChangesToSource that opens another transaction scope. Actually I know my underlying sql may have problem. What I cannot understand is why my inner transaction complete successfully and it looks like the exception is been postponed until I call outer cope.Complete??

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
      SaveChangesToSource(changes);
      scope.Complete();
}


protected override void SaveChangesToSource(IEnumerable<IChange> changes)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {            
         _bl.SaveChanges(changes);
         scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS documentation says that Changes made within the nested transaction are invisible to the top-level transaction until the nested transaction is commited, and that even then , the changes are not visible outside the top-level transaction until that transaction is commited. IMHO and If I am interpreting this correctly, then the failure of your outer transaction will trigger a roll back of your successful inner transaction.

Comment: I feel you are correct. In my scenario, it's like the inner transaction does not report error until you call outer scope.complete.. The the outer scope rollback the whole thing...